# How do i make text stand center right to an img in html/css

Tags: html, css

I want to make text stand next to an image(center)
f.eks. I want to have 3 image and 3 paragraphs of text. Each paragraph standing center-right to one of the images. Is this possible?
it feels like i have tried everything but nothing works.
(sorry for my bad english)

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
img{
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 0px
text-align: right;
}
.img-col{
  flex-basis: 50%
}
p{
  text-align: justify;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
span{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-col">
    <img src="Mundbind.jpg" alt="dani sutter" style="width:400px; height: 400px;">
  </div>
  <div class="text-col">
    <span>Hallo</span>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you visually represent what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
  img{
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 0px;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
    position: inherit;
  }
  .img-col{
    flex-basis: 50%;
    
  }
  p{
    text-align: justify;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
span{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="img-col">
<img src="Mundbind.jpg" alt="dani sutter" style="width:400px; height: 400px;">
</div>
<div class="text-col">


<span>Hallo</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way, is to work with a display flex. Look at this:

```
<div id="float">
  <div id="a">Div A</div>
  <div id="b">Div B</div>
</div>


<style>
#float{
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bezptfy3/

Here the two divs, in your case, the image and the text, are in a div with display flex. to align them to the center, you can use align-items: center and justify-content: center

For more information on positioning check out:
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for

```
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

otherwise i think you require an order property by wrapping img and text in a new container like wrapper-one and so on

```
.wrapper-one {order:1}
```

Answer (score 0):

For overlapping HTML elements, I prefer to use CSS grid.

```
<HTML>
<head>
    <style>
        .container {
            display: grid;
            align-items: center;
            text-align: center;
            grid-template-areas: "YourImage";
        }

        .img-col {
            grid-area: YourImage;
        }

        .text-col{
            grid-area: YourImage;
        }
    
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="img-col">
            <img src="Mundbind.jpg" alt="dani sutter" style="width:400px; height: 400px;">
        </div>
        <div class="text-col">
            <span>Hallo</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```